# Optimum allotment of hotel rooms based on price

Tags: algorithm, optimization, model, minimization, price

This is not a homework question. This is a problem we are facing while building an online product. Wish if someone could tell me if this is a general algorithm problem.

Suppose I have a configuration of 4 rooms:
1st room- 2 people - 800
2st room- 3 people- 1400
3rd room- 2 people - 1000
4th room- 2 people - 2000

Suppose i want to fit 4 people at minimum cost. 
Then ideally i should get 1st room + 3rd room

I tried to solve it using price/person but that would fail since it would give an output of 1st room and 2nd room

Please tell the right algorithm to solve this problem

Comment: Sounds like box packing, or [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There's a million USD prize if you can do it in polynomial time. Real systems don't look for a perfect solution but apply heuristics to get a good enough solution.

Comment: Some real systems actually use real optimization to get real optimal solutions.

Answer (score 3):

As Richard correctly stated in the comments, this is similar to Knapsack. However, it's very easy to adapt the [pseudo-polynomial dynamic programming solution from it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity).

Say you have *n* rooms and *m* people. Create a length *m + 1* vector *C*, with elements initialized to *P[i] = ∞* for *i > 0*, and *P[0] = 0*. The *i*th entry of *C* holds the best option found that can hold at least *i* people.

Now perform a triple loop:

- Loop over each room. Say the current considered room can hold *p* people at cost *c*.

  - For each *i = 0, ..., m*

    - For each *j = i, ..., min(m, i + p)*

      - Update *P[j] = min(P[j], P[i] + c)*

Check *P[m]* for the cost of the best solution.

Under the assumptions that all math costs here are constant, this has complexity *Θ(n m<sup>2</sup>)*.

---

Finding the optimal set of rooms, not just their total cost, is basically the same. In the vector, add two additional entries: one for the last room that updated the entry, and one for the last entry that updated this entry.

Comment: Taking it one notch further, suppose now I have a fixed number of rooms. This could mean higher price as long as number of room condition is being satisfied